# Add padding between the X and the content to the "you need 125 reputation" popup

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Look at what the popup looks like currently:

[image]

Currently, the element's content has a `style="padding-right: 35px;"` HTML attribute on it. Changing it to `style="padding-right: 45px;"` would add the padding:

[image]

I think the padding just belongs there. Having the [X] button so close to the text feels like it should not be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should be fixed now (and on production).